# How to set the default PDF reader from cmd line?

Tags: pdf, cmd

I need to set the default PDF reader to either Adobe Pro 2017 or Adobe Reader DC on Windows 10.

This needs to be set through the cmd line.

This needs to be done without needing to restart the machine?

Is this possible?

Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd /c ftype /?
```

Try this

Here is a thread you can look at:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4a0438a-6ef6-4dd8-b9cd-776fe2ec4ba8/setting-default-programs-in-windows-10-via-command-linepowershell